# css margin collapsing: except when the latter sibling needs to be cleared past floats

Tags: css, margin

How to understand `except when the latter sibling needs to be cleared past floats` from [Mastering margin collapsing on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)

> Adjacent siblings
>
> The margins of adjacent siblings are collapsed (**except when the latter sibling needs to be cleared past floats**).

What I tried:

```css
.box{
    background: #eee;
    margin: 10px;
}           
.xl{
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}
.yellow{
    background: yellow;
}
.red{
    background: red;
}
.float{
    float: left;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<h3>both float</h3>
<div class="example example-1">
    <div class="box xl float yellow"></div>
    <div class="box xl float red"></div>
</div>
<h3>both float while the latter with clearfix</h3>
<div class="example example-2">
    <div class="box xl float yellow"></div>
    <div class="box xl float clearfix red"></div>
</div>
<h3>foat the latter</h3>
<div class="example example-3">
    <div class="box xl yellow"></div>
    <div class="box xl float red"></div>
</div>
```

If I understand correctly, `clearfix` should applies to container instead of the siblings.

From the examples above, if siblings are float there's no margin collapsing.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the scenarios it describes